Настройка nginx ЧПУ
День добрый, использую CMS Docpart, пытаюсь прикрутить nginx. Все страницы, за исключением главной, 404.
Конфиг nginx:
    server {
    server_name *****;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/******/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/modules-includes/pagespeed/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/********.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/******.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/*********.ru;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location @php {
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/*****.ru/dynamic/*.conf;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f ******.ru";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/1.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    listen ********;
}
server {
    server_name *********.ru;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/********.ru_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/*******.ru_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/******.ru/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/modules-includes/pagespeed/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/*******.ru.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/********.ru.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/*******.ru;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location @php {
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/******.ru/dynamic/*.conf;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f *****.ru";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/1.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    listen ***** ssl http2;
}

До этого стоял Apache. Куда копать?
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web_service  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php

